# Which PHP ini file

Tags: php

When I execute the bash command `php --ini` to find the location of the `php.ini` file, the loaded one is:

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

But when I run a `php.info` on my webserver, I get this as the loaded one:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

What command can I run to return the one associated with Apache?

I remember in CentOS, I could use which php (I think) and that would return it, but using Debian it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is loaded by default when running under libapache-mod-php5, I am not sure how you can do that from the command line, *but* you can specify the ini file to be loaded manually using the `--php-ini` command line option.

For example:

```
$ php --ini --php-ini /etc/php5/apache2/
```

However, it seems that even in the above case, the `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` is parsed. Apparently, to override that directory, you may need to set it at compile-time, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183218/php-cli-does-not-use-additional-ini-files